# How do I make Dragonfly BSD boot immediately, without waiting for user input?

Tags: boot, bsd

I have installed Dragonfly BSD, and currently I need to press F1 and 1 to get it to boot. It's in a KVM VM so I'd like it to boot automatically when I boot my real machine. I know how to get KVM to start on bootup, but what I need to know is how to make Dragonfly bypass the boot prompts and boot up immediately.

Answer (score 1):

Edit `/boot.config`. Try write:

```
menu=Drop to boot prompt:prompt
default=1
timeout=5
```

I could be wrong, but it should be written in `man [boot.cfg(5)][1]`